# Ubuntu 16.04 won't transmit to TV

Tags: 16.04, sound, tv

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 as that was the last version supported for Windows XP 32-bit on a Dell Inspiron laptop. The computer has an S-video port that I connected with an adapter cable to a TV's RCA input, but there is no picture, and no sound comes from the headphone output.

When I looked at the System Tools, there is only one display - the laptop screen, and there is no TV monitor detected. Is this a flaw in Ubuntu 16.04, and is there a patch? As mentioned, I cannot upgrade to a 64-bit version.

Comment: You haven't said what model inspiron, but I used 2004 & 2005 & later ibm thinkpads, dell latitude laptops (plus a unknown year x86 only inspiron 6400) to test 18.04 flavors, inc. 18.10 & 19.04, and yes the 18.04 desktop ISO was amd64 ISO only, but x86 was supported if you used other install methods. Most monitors provide feedback (the screen saying '*Hey i'm here & can show these resolutions*') but the laptop cannot get that detail through a RCA connection, so you'll have to enable it (I used to use it to watch videos, from a laptop, but that was a decade+ ago)

Comment: Mine is an E1505 Inspiron from 2006, a simpler version of the 6400, and I just tested the VGA port on a computer monitor. Ubuntu 16.04 will recognize the second display, but not if I attach it before startup, and then, I cannot rotate it to normal. Perhaps my software is buggy.

Comment: I just hit the return key by accident, but I wonder if you can tell me the alternate way to install v.18 on a 32-bit system. Also, does anyone know a "flavor" of Linux or Ubuntu that is friendlier to 32-bit Home TV?

Comment: My dell inspiron 6400 (c2d-t2450, 2gb, intel 945gm) was used to test the default Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (Xubuntu too inc. 18.10 & 19.04 too inc., some other flavors too in 18.04 cycle) using normal ISO only as mine had 2gb RAM which is above the 700mb use case for alternate CD. There is no v18 & I've no experience with Ubuntu Core 18 as I use laptops/desktops not appliances.